# My python flask app crashes when calling a POST method

Tags: python, html, web, flask

> This is my app.py code:

````
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask import redirect, render_template as rt, url_for, request, flash

import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')


@app.route('/')
def nullPage():
    return redirect('/home/')


@app.route('/home/')
def homePage():
    return rt('homePage.html')


@app.route('/home/signup/', methods=["get", "post"])
def signUp():
    return rt('signUp.html')


@app.route('/home/login/', methods=["get", "post"])
def logIn():
    return rt('logIn.html')


@app.route('/home/logedin/', methods=["get", "post"])
def verLogIn():
    if request.method == 'post':
        passW = request.form['pass']
        email = request.form['email']
        try:
            sql_table(con)
            return "Thanks for loging in!"
        except Error:
            print(Error)
            flash(
                "An error has occured when talking to the database. Please try again later! Thank you for understanding.",
                category='error')


def sql_table(con):

    cursorObj = con.cursor()

    cursorObj.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE credentials(id integer PRIMARY KEY, email text, passWord text)"
    )
    con.commit()
    return print("Commited")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    # app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    # sess.init_app(app)
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
    # print("Bye world")```
````

> This is my html code that calls the POST method code:

```
    <!-- @format -->

    {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block head %}
    <div></div>
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/home.css') }}"
    />
    {% endblock %} {% block body %}
    <header>
        <h1>
            Hi, welcome to the WebEmailApp
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <form action="/home/signup/" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up!" id="signup" />
        </form>
        <div id="btn-sep"></div>
        <form action="/home/login/" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in!" id="login" />
        </form>
    </section>
    {% endblock %}
```

> This is my html file that is being called:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block head %}
    <div></div>
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/login.css') }}"
    />
    {% endblock %} {% block body %}
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to the log in page!</h1>
        <h5>All the field are required!</h5>
    </header>
    <section>
        <form action="/home/logedin/" method="post">
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /><br />
            <label for="pass">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </form>
    </section>
    {% endblock %}
```

> This is my error code:

```
     - - [18/Apr/2020 17:08:02] "POST /home/logedin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
        raise value
      File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
        return self.finalize_request(rv)
      File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
        response = self.make_response(rv)
     File "D:\Coding\EmailWebApp\pyenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
        raise TypeError(
    TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

I've search online for this error but everyone says that there is a function without a return line but I don't have any functions that do not return anything. Also I thought that if I reinstalled python the issue could go away but it didn't. I also tried other things that I found in some documentation online but the issue is still here. 
I tried reinstalling my IDE but no, the error message still didn't go away.

> What could I do?

Comment: def verLogIn(): -> doesn't return anything

Comment: I just realized I didn't copy the return statement. I edited the post with the return satement in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `logedin` route needs to return something.

```py
@app.route('/home/logedin/', methods=["get", "post"])
def verLogIn():
    if request.method == 'post':
        passW = request.form['pass']
        email = request.form['email']
        try:
            sql_table(con)
        except Error:
            print(Error)
            flash(
                "An error has occured when talking to the database. Please try again later! Thank you for understanding.",
                category='error')
    return rt('yourtemplate.html')  # <---- here
```

Comment: I just realized I didn't copy the return statement. I edited the post with the return satement in

Comment: Your edited post has the return in the wrong place - I believe Hoenie's answer is correct.

Comment: The return method is in the try block, does it have to be outside of the try block?